# Trying to order a query after using ROLLUP

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql, I need to order the result bellow by the year/month desc:

```
Month          Mod1    Mod2    Mod3
Jan/2013        5       4       2
Jan/2013        1       5       3
Total           6       9       5
Feb/2013        6       3       2
Feb/2013        2       1       4
Total           8       4       6
Mar/2014        6       3       2
Mar/2014        2       1       4
Total           8       4       6
```

Ordering by year/month desc should be:

```
Month          Mod1    Mod2    Mod3
Mar/2014        6       3       2
Mar/2014        2       1       4
Total           8       4       6
Feb/2013        6       3       2
Feb/2013        2       1       4
Total           8       4       6
Jan/2013        5       4       2
Jan/2013        1       5       3
Total           6       9       5
```

The query is:

```
SELECT
   month,
   year,
   SUM(IF(mod = 1, 1, 0)) AS mod1,
   SUM(IF(mod = 2, 1, 0)) AS mod2,
   SUM(IF(mod = 3, 1, 0)) AS mod3
FROM
   DW_RM_Log
WHERE
   ...
GROUP BY
   year, month
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING year IS NOT NULL AND month IS NOT NULL
```

I can't just insert ORDER BY year, month DESC at the end, because I get the following error: 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1221 Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, the `group by` does ordering.  Although *implicit* ordering is now deprecated, you can still do explicit ordering safely.  The following should do wht you want:

```
SELECT month, year,
       SUM(mod = 1) AS mod1, SUM(mod = 2) AS mod2, SUM(mod = 3) AS mod3
FROM DW_RM_Log
WHERE ...
GROUP BY year DESC, month DESC WITH ROLLUP
HAVING year IS NOT NULL AND month IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that I also simplified the `sum()` conditions.  In MySQL, you can just use the conditional itself, rather than including `if()`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question about imposing an `ORDER BY` on a `WITH ROLLUP` query, you simply need to subvert it to a sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
   month,
   year,
   SUM(IF(mod = 1, 1, 0)) AS mod1,
   SUM(IF(mod = 2, 1, 0)) AS mod2,
   SUM(IF(mod = 3, 1, 0)) AS mod3
FROM
   DW_RM_Log
WHERE
   ...
GROUP BY
   year, month
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING year IS NOT NULL AND month IS NOT NULL
) a 
ORDER BY year, month DESC
```